# PHP Facebook Stream Undefined property Error?

Tags: php, facebook, curl, stream

I followed a tutorial on creating a facebook post stream for a website I created. The stream worked fine and has done for awhile now but I just checked the website again and it is now giving me a error. Here is some of the code that I'm using, the main foreach loop that seems to be giving me an error:

And I removed some of the url string

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://graph.facebook.com/171614522965940/REMOVED SOME FOR SECURITY');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$facebook_raw = curl_exec($ch);
$facebook_json = json_decode($facebook_raw);

$facebook_data = array();
foreach($facebook_json->data as $item) {
    if($item->from->id == '658751738') {
        $facebook_item = array(
            'content' => $item->message,
            'date' => strtotime($item->created_time),
            'type' => 'facebook'
        );

        array_push($facebook_data, $facebook_item);
    }
}
```

and the error that I'm getting is:

```
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$data in /nfs/c09/h03/mnt/133481/domains/pass-out.org.uk/html/inc/fbfeed.php on line 16 Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /nfs/c09/h03/mnt/133481/domains/pass-out.org.uk/html/inc/fbfeed.php on line 16
```

Comment: There's no property "data" in $facebook_json. What result are you getting in $facebook_json?

Answer (score 0):

What does the [full] API URL return if you open it in a web browser? Or show us what  `var_dump($facebook_json)` contains. You probably have an access error, or some other error, explained in the JSON response.